# Explanation of results of load test in jmeter

Tags: php, jmeter, load-testing

I done my first load test and I have some difficulty to understand it.
I need to check how well work project with php5 and with php7.

**Screenshots of results:**

[php7 + nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBQF.png)

[php5 + apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRprR.png)

I read in google the lower average response time (blue line) means higher throughput(green line), but on my graphics it is same vector, bigger response time mean bigger throughput. How it can be true? May be I done some mistakes

Yes, php7 is faster in average response time. But it is so bit difference between php5apache and php7nginx.

If need more information, I can provide it easily.

Comment: In the php7 + nginx the response time is staying fairly constant as the throughtput increases (likely due to increasing load). You are in the nice range.  A stress test would keep increasing the load until the response time hits an "elbow (or knee)" and shoots out of sight.  php5 + apache shows steady response time and steady throughput. Looks like the load is constant.  Ask yourself, is the response time acceptable?  Only you and your client can answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you did, it's impossible to say anything coherent. But provided you ran decent number of users for some decent time, here's a couple of ideas:

**If throughput and average are both flat (horizontal line) (*php5 + apache*)** it can be

- Either you reached a saturation point, i.e. if you add any more users or requests per unit of time, throughput will not grow, but average will then grow (become worse)
- But it can also be that for given load, jmeter and/or server will not process requests any faster, however you are not at saturation point yet. I.e. adding more users, or increasing number of requests per unit of time would increase throughput, without changing average.

**If throughput is growing while average is fairly flat (*php7 + nginx*)**

- Either you are constantly increasing your load while test runs. This can either be planned (e.g. you start with very slow ramp-up) or unplanned (e.g. some logic in script causes this behavior, which you didn't intend to have, or something on JMeter environment is causing it). In this case average is quite useless, since average with lower load will affect average with higher load, especially since deviation does grow little by little.
- Or your server takes some time to ramp up (so it's able to process more requests per unit of time after running for some time, than right after test start). So you don't even see the "typical" performance yet, since graph ends while throughput is still ramping up.
- If this throughput continues to grow for hours (given constant load), that would be really really strange. The only case I can imagine is if failures are included in the average/throughput results. On some servers failures are much faster (or much slower) than successful transactions. So if failures are part of the same average, and there's a lot of them, they may affect results in some way that makes results weird like that.

So I'd say you need to exclude "growing" throughput from results and run test longer to see when does it stabilize (it will at some point, and you can reset the graph when it reaches the "horizontal line" state). You could also increase load on both tests to see if *php5 + apache* was really at saturation point.